Maven Command Failure
I receive this error when I try to save my pom.xml file:
Command failed: mvn -q help:effective-pom -Doutput=\\c:\\Users\\jackw\\Documents\\Programming\\Personal\\Time_Timer\\time_timer\\effective-pom.xml -f /c:/Users/jackw/Documents/Programming/Personal/Time_Timer/time_timer/pom.xml POM file "/c:/Users/jackw/Documents/Programming/Personal/Time_Timer/time_timer/pom.xml" specified the -f/--file command-line argument does not exist

I am not sure as to why this is happening. I am using Maven for the first time.
I am typing Ctrl+S to save my pom.xml file and I receive a Red Hat Dependency Error.

What are you typing Ctrl+S to?  And IDE?  Which one?

I am using VSCode. I am typing Ctrl+S on pom.xml

\\C:\\Users and /c:/Users seem wrong.  I would be surprised if those were valid paths.  An absolute path in Windows starts with a drive letter, with no leading slash or backslash.

this problem may be due to the wrong file location. There are a few steps you can take to try to fix the problem.

It is recommended that you check if c:\\Users\\jackw\\Documents\\Programming\\Personal\\Time_Timer\\time_timer\\effective-pom.xml exists.
Once you find the file, right-click on the file, select Properties, go to the Security tab, check whether the permissions are All (Windows) or Get Info, click on the Sharing & Permissions tab to view the permissions (mac OS).
If you're using the Maven for Java extension in VS Code, you can open the extension, search for maven for Java, and click Switch to Pre-Release Version.
Alternatively, check its settings. There might be a setting that's causing the mvn command to be run with the wrong arguments when you save the pom.xml file.
You can read more about Maven in the [documentation] (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build).

